# Как перезагрузить график после обновления данных?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

Есть код html страницы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <p class="h3" style="text-align: center;">График</p>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Выберите значение:</label>
    <select class="form-control" onChange="showSumm(this.value)" id="sel">
      <option value="Барнаул" selected>Барнаул</option>
      <option value="Итого по Компании">Итого по Компании</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>

<!-- отправка гет запроса с параметром q в файл json.php -->
<script>
function showSumm(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","json.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>


<div class="container" id="container2" style="height: 500px; min-width: 310px"></div>
<script>
Highcharts.setOptions({
  lang: {
    loading: 'Загрузка...',
    months: ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'],
    weekdays: ['Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'],
    shortMonths: ['Янв', 'Фев', 'Март', 'Апр', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Авг', 'Сент', 'Окт', 'Нояб', 'Дек'],
    exportButtonTitle: "Экспорт",
    printButtonTitle: "Печать",
    rangeSelectorFrom: "С",
    rangeSelectorTo: "По",
    rangeSelectorZoom: "Период",
    downloadPNG: 'Скачать PNG',
    downloadJPEG: 'Скачать JPEG',
    downloadPDF: 'Скачать PDF',
    downloadSVG: 'Скачать SVG',
    printChart: 'Напечатать график'
  }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON('test.json', function (data) { //test.json или json.php

  // Набор данных из таблицы
  var data_from_db = [],
    dataLength = data.length,

  i = 0;
  for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
    data_from_db.push([
      data[i][0] * 1000, // data в unix
      data[i][1], // data_from_db
    ]);
  }


  Highcharts.stockChart('container2', {

    rangeSelector: {
      selected: 1,
      buttons: [{
        type: 'day',
        count: 1,
        text: '1дн'
      }, {
        type: 'week',
        count: 1,
        text: 'нед'
      }, {
        type: 'month',
        count: 1,
        text: 'мес'
      }, {
        type: 'year',
        count: 1,
        text: 'год'
      }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'Всё'
      }]
    },

    yAxis: [{
      labels: {
        align: 'center',
        x: -3
      },
      height: '50%',
      lineWidth: 1,
      resize: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }],

    tooltip: {
      split: true
    },

    series: [{
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Общая сумма',
      data: data_from_db,
      yAxis: 0
    }]
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Есть php файл который при наличии GET запроса выполняет выборку данных из БД и записывает всё в файл test.json

```
<?php
//подключаем файл с паролями к бд
require_once './connect.php';
date_default_timezone_set( 'UTC' );

$q = $_GET['q']; 

if (empty($q)) {
    // если пусто то назначаем переменной по умолчанию 'Барнаул'
    $q = 'Барнаул';
    printf($q);
}
elseif (!empty($q)) {
    // иначе используем переменную q
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    printf($q);
}

// ну тут всё понятно, открываем соединение, выполняем запрос, разбираем ответ в массив $all, пишем в файл и закрываем соединение
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
$query = <<<EOT
SELECT
  var1.`date`,
  var1.`field_value` as name,
  var2.`field_value` as value,
  var1.`line_number`
FROM
  `online`.`VariablesValuesView` AS var1
 JOIN
  `online`.`VariablesValuesView` AS var2
  ON (var1.`line_number` = var2.`line_number`)AND (var1.`exchange_number` = var2.`exchange_number`)AND (var1.`id_variable`<>var2.`id_variable`)AND(var1.`id_variable` = 1) AND(var2.`id_variable` = 2)
WHERE var1.`field_value` = '$q' AND var1.`date` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 365 day
EOT;
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($record = $result->fetch_row()){
    $all[] =  array(strtotime($record[0]), (float)$record[2]);
    // $all[] =  array(strtotime($record[0]), $record[2]);
}
// echo json_encode($all); //на случай если нужно использовать файл json.php

file_put_contents('test.json', json_encode($all)); // пишем в файл test.json

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Как заставить обновляться график автоматически при выборе значения из select?
Пробовал `$('#container2').highcharts().redraw();` не дало результатов.. В js не силен особо. Были попытки даже обновлять div отдельно от страницы но это тоже не работает

Comment: Данные в файле test.json хранятся в таком формате `[[1576533566,696857.12],[1576619725,738142.7],[1576706127,815921.72],[1576792544,855398.15]]`

Answer (score 1):

в случае highcharts (а не highstock, хотя думаю аналогично). для обновления данных серии можно либо `chart.update()` использовать, либо `series.setData()`.

в общем, что-то у вас должно быть наподобие такого (c jquery)

```
$("#sel").change(function(){
     $.getJSON("url.php", { q: $(this).val() }, function(data){

         let mdata = data.map(function(v){
                          return [[v[0]*1000, v[1]];
                      });
         chart.series[0].setData(mdata);
         //или
         //chart.update( { series: [ data: mdata] } ); // + другие опции 
     });
});
```

где `chart` это сам график, который вы создали ранее в виде

```
 var chart = Highcharts.chart("chart-id", options);
```

зы: осталось не ясным, зачем вам сохранить данные в json-файл.

Comment: и про передачу параметров в запросы в пхп прочитайте, там где про подготовленные запросы речь идет.

Comment: Я пересмотрел свой код. Получилось что-то вроде такого. [ https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/8xTHJFnyCF ] . Теперь при попытке обновить данные, выводится всякая ерунда на графике. Вывод в файл пробовал, там вроде нормально всё, а рисует график с неверной датой и к тому же перерисовка работает криво как-то..

Comment: Точнее вот ссылка https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/gVwGJYmbzp/

Comment: решайте по одной  задаче за раз.  для начала разберитесь с исходным рисование графика. без обновлений. и не надо формировать json руками, для этого есть соответствующие функции.